On the Uniqueness of the Solution of the Wave Equation .
I am reading $\textit{Introduction to Partial Differential Equations}$ by Pinchover and Rubinstein. In this book, it is stated that the one-dimensional wave equation
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}, \quad -\infty < x < \infty,
$$
with initial conditions
$$
u(x, 0) = f(x), \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x, 0) = g(x),
$$
has a unique solution if $ f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}) $ and $ g \in C^1(\mathbb{R}) $, and is well-posed if $ 0 \leq t \leq T, T \in \mathbb{R} $.
I would like to address the same question for the finite domain problem:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}, \quad 0 \leq x \leq L,
$$
with initial conditions
$$
u(x, 0) = f(x), \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x, 0) = g(x),
$$
and boundary conditions
$$
u(0, t) = 0, \quad u(L, t) = 0 \quad \text{(Dirichlet boundary conditions)}.
$$
$\textbf{1. Under what conditions does the above wave equation have a  solution?}$
$\textbf{2. Under what conditions does the above wave equation have a unique solution?}$
$\textbf{3. Under what conditions the above problem well-posed?}$
Thank you in advance.

Standard techniques apply, hints:

If there are two solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$, consider $w=u_1 - u_2$, you need to find the PDE $w$ should satisfy and argue that $w\equiv 0$.

Extend $f$ and $g$ to the whole domain such that their extensions still are $C^2$- and $C^1$-smooth, respectively, use d'Alembert's formula (or the well-posedness result you mentioned) to argue that there exists a solution on the whole domain. Then, restricting this whole-domain solution to the finite interval in consideration, argue that this restriction is still a solution to the wave equation on the finite interval. Combining with 1 you have the well-posedness.



Thank you. And my last question is when solution exist? (Edited)

@neelkanth If you use the extension argument, the solution exists on the whole interval, then you need to make an argument that this solution (already exists), when restricted on the finite interval, is also a solution on the finite interval (verify it satisfies the initial/boundary conditions, the original PDE). If you correctly show these, the solution exists.
